# Qt: How to use the returned QVariant from evaluateJavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I am using Qt 4.8.1 with the evaluateJavaScript function to want to get some DOM elements back into a Qt application. The code I used is :

```
QVariant paragraphs = view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName(\"p\")");
const char* returnTypeName = paragraphs.typeName();
std::cout << "returnTypeName = " << returnTypeName << std::endl;
```

I find that :

```
returnTypeName = QVariantMap
```

However, I do not know the actual return type in the QVariantMap.

I want to know that could I find out the actual type in the returned QVariantMap ? Could I convert the QVariantMap to a QWebElement / QWebElementCollection ? Or how could I use the returned QVariantMap (as I have no experience in using QVariant objects).

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Are you familiar with (i) maps/dictionaries/lookup-tables, and (ii) variants, in general?

Comment: I know the concept of Maps/Dictionaries but I am new to Qt and its QVariant.

Comment: A variant is like a JavaScript `var` -- it can store different datatypes. It is available in different languages (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type). My answer shows you how to extract the data stored in a Qt variant.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is consult the [QVariant documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html). Qt documentation is very comprehensive; make good use of it.

Anyway, a `QVariantMap` is a typedef of `QMap<QString, QVariant>`. So, you use string keys (variable names) to extract individual values.

```
// Convert your result into the underlying map
QVariantMap returnedMap = paragraphs.toMap();

// Get some values
QVariant value1 = returnedMap["key1"];
QVariant value2 = returnedMap["key2"];

// Find out their types
std::cout << "Type 1 = " << value1.typeName() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Type 2 = " << value1.typeName() << std::endl;

// Convert them to their underlying types
// (assuming value1 is a string, value2 is an int)
QString str = value1.toString();
int number = value2.toInt();
```

Comment: This answer is a little too trivial to be useful here. OP was not looking to extract a primitive data type (string or integer) but a set of QWebElement objects as returned by the javascript instruction. The QVariant documentation isn't clear on how to do this particular conversion, and no `toWebElement()` function is provided.

Comment: @dwk: Read the question carefully, as well as the comments under the question. The OP simply wanted info on how to extract data from a `QVariant`/`QVariantMap`, and this answer provides that info. The OP only mentioned `QWebElement` as his/her 1st attempt to find a solution, but this attempt doesn't work. (For the record, you cannot possibly convert the return value of `evaluateJavaScript()` into `QWebElements`. In this case, the return value simply represents a **JavaScript Object**, not the components of a web page.)

Comment: @dwk: Oops, it was I who didn't read the question properly. Thanks for pointing that out, and for posting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As JKSH suggested, if you want to pull a DOM element into Qt in a useful form for manipulating that object, you can't use a Javascript evaluation to do so, as a Javascript element reference can't be converted into a QWebElement object.

To obtain a DOM element in Qt, you need to use Qt methods directly. This code should return the QWebElementCollection you were looking for without the need for a Javascript evaluation:

```
QWebElementCollection paragraphs = view->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findAll("p");
```